# React native testing with Jest using styled components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

Getting the following error:
    TypeError: _styledComponents.default.View is not a function
Using styles as code from below:

```
const LoadingWrap = styled.View`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.buttonColor};
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 15px;
  width: ${(props) => (props.small ? '100px' : '90%')};
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 80px;
  elevation: 3;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install and `import 'jest-styled-components';` into your test file when using styled-components.

Some docs here: https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components#jest-styled-components that you might find useful.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response. I have installed jest-styled-components and I have added import 'jest-styled-components';into my test files.
Still facing the same issue 
TypeError: _styledComponents.default.View is not a function

Comment: Okay, could you edit your post to include the test file as well as the usage of `LoadingWrap` in your app?